# Is there any travel insurance where I don't have to be registered with GP?

Tags: schengen, uk, international-travel, insurance

I'm Indian citizen, staying in UK on ICT Tier 2 short term and planning to apply for Schengen Visa.
In order to apply for Schengen Visa I need travel insurance, hence I checked few  travel insurances and they have a clause according to which I need to register with GP, which I'm not at the moment. So is there any travel insurance where I don't have to be registered with a GP?

Also I've initiated the registration process with GP but I'm not sure whether it'll be complete by the day I've my appointment with TLS.

Comment: Is it only me that is not aware of what _GP_ means? Can you, please, clarify that on your question?

Comment: @gmauch: In the UK, a "GP" is a General Practitioner: a generalist doctor who provides primary health care and is the entry point to the wider National Health Service.

Comment: I honestly never realised that you need to be registered with a GP to buy travel insurance.  I've bought travel insurance many times in the past and can't remember the question of GP registration ever come up. The last one I bought from insureandgo - about a year ago.  Not to say that this isn't hidden somewhere in the small print that I didn't find (although I always read small print).

Comment: @AleksG I couldn't find it in the policy document for Insureandgo and I even confirmed on the call as well. Also it's mentioned in the documents of other providers.

Comment: Well, if you confirmed it with Insureandgo, then here's your answer :)

Comment: Was on insure and go website with an advisor and he stated yes you have to be registered with gp

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed by **user9792** himself, Insureandgo has no such clause in their [policy wording](https://www.insureandgo.com/travel-insurance/policy-wording) and is available to UK residents.

Comment: Answer seems like it's no longer valid. "You must have lived in the UK for at least 6 of the last 12 months. You must have a permanent UK address and be registered with a medical practitioner in the UK." - on [site](https://www.insureandgo.com/CGI-BIN/LANSAWEB?PROCFUN+INSUREGO+IAG7001+ALC+ENG)